# Baguettebox doesn't show next/previous stepper

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, baguettebox

I'm using baguettebox for image  viewer. The problem is, everything works except the "next/previous" buttons. So I can't go to the next image.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>

<script>
   baguetteBox.run('.labrador');
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<div class="labrador">
      <a href="img/portfolio/cabin.png"
       data-at-450="img/portfolio/blog.jpg"
       data-at-800="img/portfolio/cake.png"
       data-at-1366="img/portfolio/circus.png"
       data-at-1920="img/portfolio/blog.jpg">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Images</button>
            </a>
          </div>
```

My result: 
https://i.gyazo.com/3e9bad7f104794962a31b8ef13ce0891.png

As you can see, there aren't next/prev buttons, only the X which works fine.

Comment: Are the next/prev buttons rendered in the HTML of the carousel? If yes, It could be a problem in your CSS, if not,  do you have a console error?

Comment: I don't have any errors. I just checked it again, and got this result: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/9b14f6666618ea708727e1270d985dd3.mp4)  As you can see, I could go next/prev with right/left arrow keys, but it perceives only one picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your script add this `{buttons: true}` in `baguetteBox`
try this

```
baguetteBox.run('.labrador',{
  buttons: true
});
```

```js
baguetteBox.run('.labrador',{
  buttons: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/css/baguetteBox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="labrador">
      <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-1.jpg"
       data-at-450="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-1.jpg"
       data-at-800="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-3.jpg"
       data-at-1366="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-4.jpg"
       data-at-1920="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-2.jpg">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Images</button>
            </a>
             <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/2-1.jpg"
       data-at-450="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-1.jpg"
       data-at-800="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-3.jpg"
       data-at-1366="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-4.jpg"
       data-at-1920="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/4-2.jpg">
            </a>
          </div>
```

check this example

```js
baguetteBox.run('.labrador',{
  buttons: true
});
```

```css
img{
          height:50px;
          margin:10px 0;
        }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/css/baguetteBox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
      
         <div class="labrador">
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-1.jpg" data-caption="Golden Gate Bridge">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-1.jpg" alt="Golden Gate Bridge">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-2.jpg" title="Midnight City">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-2.jpg" alt="Midnight City">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-3.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-3.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-4.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-4.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-5.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-5.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-6.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-6.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-7.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-7.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/1-8.jpg">
            <img src="https://feimosi.github.io/baguetteBox.js/img/thumbs/1-8.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: The next/prev buttons are solved with this, but still stuck in the first image. (With your code snippet too)

Comment: for that you have to add multiple images then it will works, check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

*Try the below code or visit this link:
https://www.cssscript.com/simple-gallery-lightbox-with-javascript-and-css3-baguettebox-js/*

```
baguetteBox.run('.labrador', {
  captions: true, // display image captions.
  buttons: 'auto', // arrows navigation
  fullScreen: false,
  noScrollbars: false,
  bodyClass: 'baguetteBox-open',
  titleTag: false,
  async: false,
  preload: 2,
  animation: 'slideIn', // fadeIn or slideIn
  verlayBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)'
});
```